# While Getting Firebase Document Reference id in Codable Struct it Shows error as " Invalid type in JSON write (FIRDocumentReference)"

Tags: swift, firebase, google-cloud-firestore, struct, codable

I am trying to use firebase reference as a datatype in codable struct

struct MainCategory: Codable {
let categoryID:DocumentReference?
let categoryName: String
}

Comment: The error says that you are trying to encode an object which is not (En)Codable compliant.

Comment: Take a look at the [Codable Walkthrough](https://peterfriese.dev/posts/firestore-codable-the-comprehensive-guide/) to get some pointers.